# Bullets in document getting as a question mark in GATE NLP

Tags: java, encoding, nlp, stanford-nlp, gate

I am new to `GATE NLP`. I have a document, which contains bullets. When I load it into `GATE`. Bullets are detected as an unknown type symbol which is printed as `` . I also tried to set the encoding to `UTF-8`. And I also tryed to load the document programmatically, then bullets gets detected as a  `?` .

Can anyone explain me this?

Example:

` Promoted to Senior Member Technical in 2.5 years of experience.`

Here is the symbol which is in the `GATE DEVELOPER UI` and the `?` symbol is shown when I did it "programmatically".

Comment: You have to provide more details, otherwise your question cannot be answered... E.g.: what kind of file (txt,pdf, doc,docx) are you loading?  What do you mean by "loading programmatically"? Can you post the relevant part of your source code?

Comment: For `pdf` this may be related: _In WinAnsiEncoding, any unused code greater than 040 maps to the bullet character_
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1713

Comment: It's for the pdf ,doc , Docx . Programmatically meanes  , I am using embedded gate to load the document and execute it with a pipeline .When i execute it , then ? are there .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, `doc` and `docx` files usually do not produce `` characters. Bullets are either missing (text formatted as bullet-list) or printed as `•` (text with raw bullet characters).

See also this related question: [Parsing either font style or block of paragraph in GATE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33255580/1857897)

`Pdf` files often produce "``-bullet characters" in a GATE document. It may be related to some *pdf* or *Apache PDFBox* issues, see e.g. [this one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1713).

These characters also have a unicode value. In XML, they are encoded for example as `&#xf0b7;`. In this case, my advice is to trace such characters (they may have different unicode values depending on the original bullet character) and replace them by something printable (e.g. `•`).

Concerning the `?` characters: I it is probably caused by your java environment which doesn't support these characters. See e.g.: [Why Some Unicode Characters appears to be question mark in the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18856056/1857897)

Comment: yes , the problem is with the pdf documents . Now I am converting doc to HTML and then processing HTML document . So , It's working for me .thanks @dedek